# VB6 Initialize event called AFTER Terminate event for user controls

Tags: vb6

I have created a simple form in VB6, and added a simple, blank user control. The only code are Debug.Print statements in all major events.

For some reason, when the form is closed, the order of events in the User Control are:

```
Terminate
Initialize
Read Properties
Resize
```

Why is this happening? Why are Initialize, ReadProperties and Resize called after Terminate? I could not find any evidence of this in Microsoft documentation.

EDIT:

Here is the code.

User control:

```
VERSION 5.00
Begin VB.UserControl UserControl1 
   ClientHeight    =   3600
   ClientLeft      =   0
   ClientTop       =   0
   ClientWidth     =   4800
   ScaleHeight     =   3600
   ScaleWidth      =   4800
End
Attribute VB_Name = "UserControl1"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = True
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Private Sub UserControl_Initialize()
    Debug.Print "Initialize"
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_InitProperties()
    Debug.Print "InitProperties"
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_ReadProperties(PropBag As PropertyBag)
    Debug.Print "ReadProperties"
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_Resize()
    Debug.Print "Resize"
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_Show()
    Debug.Print "Show"
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_Terminate()
    Debug.Print "Terminate"
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_WriteProperties(PropBag As PropertyBag)
    Debug.Print "WriteProperties"
End Sub
```

Form:

```
VERSION 5.00
Begin VB.Form Form1 
   Caption         =   "Form1"
   ClientHeight    =   3030
   ClientLeft      =   120
   ClientTop       =   450
   ClientWidth     =   4560
   LinkTopic       =   "Form1"
   ScaleHeight     =   3030
   ScaleWidth      =   4560
   StartUpPosition =   3  'Windows Default
   Begin Project1.UserControl1 UserControl1 
      Height          =   2535
      Left            =   240
      TabIndex        =   0
      Top             =   240
      Width           =   4095
      _extentx        =   7223
      _extenty        =   4471
   End
End
Attribute VB_Name = "Form1"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
```

Comment: That's not possible to happen - it's almost guaranteed to be something with your code (and logging) but we won't be able to tell without the code.

Comment: Well, here's the VERY SIMPLE code that shows how this happens. If you still have trouble believing, I'll do a screen recording and send you the video.

Comment: keep it nice people! ..... your user control is loaded again after being terminated ... this could be caused by accessing (reading) a property of the user control .. please post the code of the form where it is terminated and any code that could happen after that

Comment: @Hrqls - thanks for the comment. I did post the code, it does absolutely nothing except calling Debug.Print (as you can see). Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: i meant the code of your form ... it read/sets properties of the user control i guess ? maybe some actions on/with/from the user control are done in the form when it closes down?

Comment: @user884248 I reverted my -1 because you added your code.

Comment: @xxbbcc - thank you. deleted my somewhat angry comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Debug.Print` means your running this in debug mode in the IDE.

When debugging you would see a `Terminate` when the form unloads, you then see the reinitialisation of the User Control as its re-loaded in the Form in the *Form Designer* for editing.

This won't happen from a compiled EXE, you can replace `Debug.Print` with `MsgBox` to verify this.

Comment: Alex K. - you're a genius. I'm a little embarrased that I didn't think about this myself. Thank you!